# How to add Android Contacts into a listview with a check box

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts, android-checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I link a checkbox for every contact in populated listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544821/how-do-i-link-a-checkbox-for-every-contact-in-populated-listview)

i m a beginner in `android`.

> i want to get the phone contacts and then put them into a `listview`
>   with a checkbox so that user can select more then one contact and then
>   get the selected contacts.

is there any `tutorial` for that????

thanks

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450058/using-checkbox-to-filter-contacts-and-get-phone-number/10105655#10105655]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450058/using-checkbox-to-filter-contacts-and-get-phone-number/10105655#10105655

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544821/how-do-i-link-a-checkbox-for-every-contact-in-populated-listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code to get all contacts with checkbox :

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
  while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
      // This inner cursor is for contacts that have multiple numbers.
      Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
      while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        phoneContactList.add(name);
        Log.i("Contact List", name);
      }
      pCur.close();
    }
  }

  Collections.sort(phoneContactList);
  cnt = phoneContactList.size();

  listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.drawable.multiple_contact_selector, phoneContactList));
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

}
cur.close();
```

Comment: and add permission in manifest file as : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you :  [Custom Android ListView to read phone contacts](http://vikasdp.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/custom-android-listview-to-read-phone-contacts/) .

First of all check this

1) Add permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```