# custom ListView checkbox with radio button?

Tags: android

I called a web service and get result Option_type `Check box` and Option_type `Radio Button` then I used a **custom list view** and **base adapter also**.

**But check box means should have multiple check but radio button only one selected option.**

How can implement coding in base adapter class get view method.

Comment: have you tried out anything ?

Comment: s i will sent it code

Comment: i have used it base adapter in list view.So we need to implement in View holder class.

Comment: Look , you have to post your code for the Adapter class where you inflate the layout inside the getview method of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you. Just copy paste code in four different files. Two are xml and two are java then you can run project directly.

[How do I link a checkbox for every contact in populated listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544821/how-do-i-link-a-checkbox-for-every-contact-in-populated-listview/10545729#10545729)